# loop linear model with different variables condition in r

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lm

I want to make a loop for the linear model but get a problem.

First, I write a loop(can not run) that extracts the beta value I wanted.

```
y <- c('y1', 'y2')
x1 <- c('a1', 'a2', 'a3')
x2 <- c('A', 'B')

for (y in y) {
  for (x1 in x1) {
    for (x2 in x2) {
      m <- lm(as.name(y) ~ as.name(x1) + as.name(x2), data = dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

The combination of `y`, `x1`, and `x2` in the for loop is not my expectation. The formula in `lm` model like this: `expand.grid(y, x1, x2)`. And what I expected is all the combination of the same letter on the independent variable position. This is my original code:

````
m1 <- lm(y1 ~ a1 + A, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m2 <- lm(y1 ~ a2 + A, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m3 <- lm(y1 ~ a3 + A, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m4 <- lm(y2 ~ a1 + A, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m5 <- lm(y2 ~ a2 + A, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m6 <- lm(y2 ~ a3 + A, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m7 <- lm(y1 ~ b1 + B, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m8 <- lm(y1 ~ b2 + B, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m9 <- lm(y1 ~ b3 + B, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m10 <- lm(y2 ~ b1 + B, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m11 <- lm(y2 ~ b2 + B, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]
m12 <- lm(y2 ~ b3 + B, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1]```
````

And this is my data.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
dat <- structure(list(y1 = c(0.838141931, 0.174850172, 0.116144283, 
0.113778511, 0.494270733, 0.874482265, 0.325621743, 0.661045636, 
0.452396096), y2 = c(0.487877797, 0.360726955, 0.380614137, 0.169760207, 
0.359371965, 0.743837108, 0.156535906, 0.995989192, 0.331058618
), a1 = c(0.336537159, 0.446060609, 0.57586382, 0.09629329, 0.491634112, 
0.988226873, 0.929105257, 0.605957031, 0.470720774), a2 = c(0.128615421, 
0.831986313, 0.267777151, 0.313178319, 0.7776461, 0.863337292, 
0.042818986, 0.830029959, 0.901586271), a3 = c(0.291053766, 0.546719865, 
0.918797744, 0.976353885, 0.193777436, 0.953859399, 0.963312236, 
0.191449484, 0.825034161), b1 = c(0.31510338, 0.5441007, 0.515466925, 
0.030702511, 0.020932599, 0.334734486, 0.586588252, 0.562970761, 
0.848337089), b2 = c(0.426787995, 0.350719803, 0.706471337, 0.346462166, 
0.099766511, 0.219781154, 0.565047862, 0.50282167, 0.727813725
), b3 = c(0.799666435, 0.07225825, 0.409411895, 0.701122141, 
0.529991257, 0.478439097, 0.79467065, 0.442156618, 0.026693511
), A = c(0.43143391, 0.662313075, 0.584967093, 0.866110621, 0.598682492, 
0.14665666, 0.454315631, 0.448968611, 0.238969939), B = c(0.060625179, 
0.410312393, 0.614411256, 0.127343899, 0.90370096, 0.882024428, 
0.681389602, 0.56535592, 0.850829599)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(y1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), y2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), a3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), b3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), A = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), B = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. Can you explain? Maybe also show expected output for the data shared.

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry, and I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need: y ~ b[1-3] + B and y ~ a[1-3] + A and don't need y ~ a[1-3] + B and y ~ b[1-3] + A, then you can set up the data.frame like this:

```
library(dplyr)

res = rbind(
expand.grid(response=c('y1', 'y2'),pre1=c('a1', 'a2', 'a3'),pre2='A',stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
expand.grid(response=c('y1', 'y2'),pre1=c('b1', 'b2', 'b3'),pre2='B',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)
```

From parts of your code, it seems like you only need the 2nd coefficient, so a simple base R method will be to use `reformulate` to construct the formula for every row:

```
res$coef = sapply(1:nrow(res),function(i){
predictor = as.character(res[i,c("pre1","pre2")])
response = res$response[i]
f = reformulate(predictor,response=response)
coefficients(lm(f,data=dat))[2]
})

       head(res)
  response pre1 pre2         coef
1       y1   a1    A -0.254942513
2       y2   a1    A -0.005955600
3       y1   a2    A -0.006177156
4       y2   a2    A  0.286669786
5       y1   a3    A -0.393284033
6       y2   a3    A -0.387500900
```

A tidy solution will be something like this, where we nest the models first

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

res = rbind(
expand.grid(response=c('y1', 'y2'),pre1=c('a1', 'a2', 'a3'),pre2='A',stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
expand.grid(response=c('y1', 'y2'),pre1=c('b1', 'b2', 'b3'),pre2='B',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)

res = res %>% 
mutate(model=1:n()) %>% 
nest(param=c(c(response, pre1, pre2))) %>% 
mutate(
fit = map(param,~
lm(reformulate(c(.$pre1,.$pre2),response=.$response),data=dat)),
tidied=map(fit,tidy)
)
```

The model and results are nested in a tibble:

```
    res
    # A tibble: 12 x 4
   model param            fit    tidied          
   <int> <list>           <list> <list>          
 1     1 <tibble [1 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [3 × 5]>
 2     2 <tibble [1 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [3 × 5]>
 3     3 <tibble [1 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [3 × 5]>
 4     4 <tibble [1 × 3]> <lm>   <tibble [3 × 5]>
```

And if you need the 2nd coefficient:

```
res %>% unnest(c(param,tidied)) %>% filter(term==pre1)
    # A tibble: 12 x 10
   model response pre1  pre2  fit    term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <list> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1 y1       a1    A     <lm>   a1    -0.255       0.390   -0.653   0.538 
 2     2 y2       a1    A     <lm>   a1    -0.00596     0.479   -0.0124  0.990 
 3     3 y1       a2    A     <lm>   a2    -0.00618     0.246   -0.0251  0.981 
 4     4 y2       a2    A     <lm>   a2     0.287       0.268    1.07    0.325 
 5     5 y1       a3    A     <lm>   a3    -0.393       0.176   -2.24    0.0664
 6     6 y2       a3    A     <lm>   a3    -0.388       0.233   -1.66    0.148 
 7     7 y1       a1    B     <lm>   a1     0.507       0.541    0.937   0.385 
 8     8 y2       a1    B     <lm>   a1     0.372       0.510    0.729   0.493 
 9     9 y1       a2    B     <lm>   a2     0.182       0.391    0.466   0.657 
10    10 y2       a2    B     <lm>   a2     0.436       0.319    1.37    0.221 
11    11 y1       a3    B     <lm>   a3    -0.371       0.310   -1.19    0.277 
12    12 y2       a3    B     <lm>   a3    -0.381       0.276   -1.38    0.217
```

Comment: I think something wrong with the code. I need y ~ **b[1-3]** + **B** and y ~ **a[1-3]** + **A** and don't need y ~ **a[1-3]** + **B** and y ~ **b[1-3]** + **A** .

Comment: then just modify the data.frame to start with? Again it's really not very clear. See if updated answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got you right, but it seems you've organized your data in the wrong way. Maybe this is what you might want to:

```
new_dat = data.frame(
  y = c(rep(dat$y1, 3 + 3), rep(dat$y2, 3 + 3)),
  x = c(rep(c(dat$a1, dat$a2, dat$a3), 2),
        rep(c(dat$b1, dat$b2, dat$b3), 2)),
  z = c(rep(dat$A, 3 + 3), rep(dat$B, 3 + 3))
)

models = with(new_dat, mapply(function(y, x, z) model = lm(y ~ x + z),
                              y, x, z, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

Let us know if that's exactly what you're looking for. If not, elaborate on it...

Comment: Sorry for the confused expression and I update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `expand.grid` you can create all combinations of `y`, `x1` and `x2`. Create formula as strings using `sprintf`.

```
df <- expand.grid(y, x1, x2)
formula_strings <- sprintf('%s ~ %s + %s', df$Var1, df$Var2, df$Var3)
formula_strings

# [1] "y1 ~ a1 + A" "y2 ~ a1 + A" "y1 ~ a2 + A" "y2 ~ a2 + A"
# [5] "y1 ~ a3 + A" "y2 ~ a3 + A" "y1 ~ a1 + B" "y2 ~ a1 + B"
# [9] "y1 ~ a2 + B" "y2 ~ a2 + B" "y1 ~ a3 + B" "y2 ~ a3 + B"
```

Using `sapply` apply the model and extract coefficients from each.

```
values <- sapply(formula_strings, function(x) 
                 lm(x, dat) %>% summary() %>% .$coefficients %>% .[2,1])
values

#y1 ~ a1 + A y2 ~ a1 + A y1 ~ a2 + A y2 ~ a2 + A y1 ~ a3 + A y2 ~ a3 + A 
#  -0.254943   -0.005956   -0.006177    0.286670   -0.393284   -0.387501 
#y1 ~ a1 + B y2 ~ a1 + B y1 ~ a2 + B y2 ~ a2 + B y1 ~ a3 + B y2 ~ a3 + B 
#   0.506848    0.371615    0.182370    0.435684   -0.370723   -0.380668
```